# Access Dart / Polymer WebComponent from main

Tags: dart, polymer

Think of the following: 
I've got a table data grid webcomponent and another component providing a data feed. In the applications main acting as kind of controller, i'd like to wire and setup those two components. Therefore i need a reference to underlying table grid instance Dart class and call methods on the "Component API' (to provide the table grid's tablemodel with data).

How do I access the Dart Class instance of a webcomponent instance from *outside* ?

Probably I missed something fundamental or are polymer webcomponents meant to interact only using databinding and stringy attributes stuff ?

Follow up: Found it !!

```
RLTable table = querySelector("#apptable").xtag;
```

does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zoechi pointed out, xtag is not necessary.

```dart
var component = $['myComp'];
var componentXtag = $['myComp'].xtag;
print(component == componentXtag);
```

prints true. Therefore both

```dart
component.method()
componentXtag.method()
```

work fine

Comment: thx, somehow missed that in darts documentation muddle .. (not that i am reading it from start to end .. ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need xtag. Some weeks/months ago this was a workaround until the final solution was landed.

Comment: What do you mean by "the final solution"?

Comment: er .. and what was the final solution ?

Comment: xtag was an tansistional solution. Since a while you can access the object directly without xtag.